# React native Expo Sdk 48: I can't swipe to open drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I observed that I could no longer **swipe** to open drawer navigator in **expo sdk 48** after my update. This wasn't a problem in the previous versions.

I did `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` at the top of the app file according to the documentation.

Please, share how you were able to resolve it.

My dependencies are;

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.18",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "zustand": "^4.3.8"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to resolve it by installing expo sdk49 and running `npx expo install --fix`  after installing `npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).